# iOS cell add target not working properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, target

In my app I've written the following code in a `UICollectionView` `cellForRowAtIndexpath` like this `[CollectionView Cell is a custom cell]`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"localMusicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

[[cell.downImageButton viewWithTag:indexPath.item] addTarget:self action:@selector(downImgClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
}
```

and the target method like this:

```
-(void)downImgClicked:(UIButton*)button{

}
```

And there are four items in `UICollectionView`, but for first item only this target method is called and for rest of them its not even triggering why?

Comment: i think you want `[cell.downImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downImgClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: @Nishant I need to pass the indexPath.item also the target? how?

Comment: Use `cell.downImageButton.tag = indexPath.item;` AND THEN in the target method, `-(void)downImgClicked:(UIButton*)button{ 
int indexPathItem = button.tag;
}`

Comment: Thanks Nishant its working now, What is the problem with my code?

Comment: `[cell.downImageButton viewWithTag:indexPath.item]` returns a subview of the `downImageButton` and the target was being added to that (which might be nil). You needed to add the target to the button itself. You can go through the documentation for `viewWithTag:` method.

Comment: @Nishant Got it thank you

Answer (score 3):

try alternate way

```
cell.downImageButton.tag = indexPath.item;
[cell.downImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downImgClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

call method like

```
-(void)downImgClicked:(UIButton*)button{
  NSLog (@"selected index ==%@",button.tag);
 }
```

Comment: nothing problem bro, sometimes userinteaction not reacheable may be

Answer (score 3):

try this way,

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AllCollectionViewCell

        cell.playBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.playBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonAction:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell

    }
```

target method:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SampleViewController") as! PlayViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
```

its working for me, hope its helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"localMusicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.downImageButton.tag =indexPath.row;
    [cell.downImageButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(downImgClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;

}
```

and the target method like this:

```
-(void)downImgClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
 long selectedBtnRow;

 selectedBtnRow = button.tag;

 NSLog (@"selected index ==>%ld",selectedBtnRow);
}
```